# Integrate CKFinder with ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ckfinder, ckeditor.net

I just downloaded the Free Trial of latest CKFinder v2.4.2 for ASP.Net and added the ckfinder folder in my ASP.Net webforms project running on .Net v4.0 I was able to run the standalone.aspx page present in _samples/aspx folder but when trying to run the ckeditor.aspx page, it throws me this error -

**Could not load file or assembly 'CKEditor.NET' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

I have added references to CKfinder.dll to my project and double checked the existence of CKFinder.dll file in my bin folder. I have read the documentation repeated times, but could not find a solution to this problem.

In ckeditor.aspx page, it says -

- This is the ASP.NET connector for CKFinder.
  *
- You must copy the CKFinder.Connector.dll file to your "bin" directory or
- make a reference to it in your Visual Studio project.

but I could not find any dll named CKFinder.Connector.dll file in the downloaded folder. Attached is a screenshot showing how the ckfinder and ckeditor folders sit in my project.

Any help???[image: Capture.png]

Comment: Maybe this post can help: http://forums.asp.net/t/1909728.aspx?Could+not+load+type+CKFinder+Connector+Connector+

Comment: @Greenonion the post says "make sure that the folder /ckfinder is configured as an application", I am trying to execute it from VS inside a large web application, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I've added original source of CKFinder class library in my project and referred the dll.